# Please solve this?

Tags: html

I made small project on JSP. When I enter id  and submit, it shows(id,name,cost, available) it's ok, but when I enter name it's not display any data.why MySQL not read string variable I am not understanding?it's not any error and exception.

```
String q="Select from product where id="+id; ✓
String q="select from product where name='name'";×
```

What can I do?

Comment: Because ‘name’ doesn’t exist in db? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

First, it's not good practice to construct queries with +. It will  lead [sql injection attact](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/).

To solve your problem. This has to work. Your

```
String q="select from product where name like ’name’";
```

Answer (score 0):

String name = "john";
 String sql = "select * from product  where name = '" + name + "':   resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);

I miss the double quotations and + symbol  around the name...
    That's why values are not printed.